# A problem to understand the given exercise

Tags: abstract-algebra, simple-groups

I am trying to solve a problem which says,Let $G$ be a group and $H$ be a subgroup of finite index.show that $G$ contains a normal subgroup of finite index.

Actually I cann't except this statement as I know if we consider $A_5$ I get a cyclic subgroup generated by $(1 2)(1 3)(1 4)(1 5)$,Then we get a subgroup with index $14$.According to the above statement $A_5$ has a normal subgroup of finite index which contradicts to the fact that $A_5$ is simple.

My question is am I correct to read the question or I have done some silly mistake to understand it.If I am wrong then how should I proceed,give me a hint in that case,please.

Comment: $A_5$ has a (trivial) normal subgroup of (finite) index 60. The problem is really interesting only for infinite groups, as it is trivial for finite ones.

Comment: $A_5$ is simple as if $H$ is normal in $A_5$ then $H$ contains $3$ cycle and hence coincides to $A_5$.

Comment: That is true if $H $ is **nontrivial** normal subgroup. The trivial subgroup is always normal.

Comment: yes,of course....actually I did not see the word "trivial",I apologies

Comment: Now, for the proof, go through Wikipedia article https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_of_a_subgroup , section "Finite index", and come back with more questions if this is unclear. Have a good day.

Comment: Thank you,Wikipedia has used Extended Caley's Theorem,There the kernel of homomophism  is considered as the normal subgroup.But it may be trivial.what is the usefulness of the above problem as I know any group contains trivial subgroup and it's normal?

Comment: As I said, the problem is interesting for an infinite group $G $, in which case the trivial subgroup is not of a finite index, and so you need to find another one!